# Just render shadows and reflections

Tags: rendering, materials

What I want basically want to create is this

[image]

Therefore I good some spheres on a plane and some lighting.
My problem is, that I want to have all the shadows and the reflections of the plane on the spheres, but I want the complete plane to be one color. So the plane shouldn't be affected by the light.

I think there should be two solutions, which I both don't know how to do them:

1. Render a complete white plane which is not affected by light
2. Render a transparent plane which is should receive shadows and affect the reflections of the spheres.

Has anyone an idea how to do one of this? (Number 2 would be better for me)

Comment: you could add an ambient occlusion shader to the plane

Comment: Sorry, but it seems that it doesn't work how I want. If I add a plane above the spheres (for the reflections on the spheres) the planes is also affected by this plane. And then again it has no more solid color. Also the color of the plane is not completely white.

Comment: I am comprising an answer. But I am also very busy

Comment: I've uploaded an image: http://www.pasteall.org/pic/67870

Comment: are you using an HDR or a lamp as your light source? Also is this cycles?

Comment: Yes this is in cycles. Now I don't use an HDR Image. I want to use a plane for the reflections on the sphere and an area light for the shadows.

Comment: I just tried the whole thing with and HDR and I think I will use this now, because this works better. But everything still in cycles

Comment: so you have gotten rid of the lamps?

Comment: No just the plane above the spheres. There is still an area light.

Comment: what are you using the HDR and the AREA for?

Comment: I use the want to use the HDR for the Reflections on the top of the sphere and the area for the shadows on the plane. The problem if I would use a plane instead of an HDR is, that i don't know how to make the plane completely white. So the reflections on the sphere should also be completely white.

Comment: this seems to be quite complicated, getting a shadow pass alone seems to be an adeventure

Comment: Hm, I thought it is an easy step and I simply don't know how to do it.

Comment: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8888/the-renderfarm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use an Ambient Occlusion Shader for the plane. This will give the plane a constant color while still giving you the desired ambient shadows without the shadows from the light source. By default the Ambient Occlusion is pretty weak. We can use the compositor to make the Ambient Occlusion more prominent.

1. Add an Ambient Occlusion Shader to the plane
2. Enable the AO render pass

   [image]
3. In the compositor:

   - use the RGB Curves or a similar node to make the AO pass darker
   - Invert: needed to properly control the factor input
   - Use the Multiply node to control the strength of the darkening
   - Subtract: this is a Color -> Mix node. This is the final output

   [image]

NOTE: you can use the *Distance* parameter in the *World* Panel to change the proximity in which Ambient Occlusion is shown.

---

AO before vs. after compositing

[image]

Comment: First of all thanks. But what is this Subtract node. Where did you get that from? It isn't a math node is it? And did you used an HDR for the reflections on the spheres?

Comment: Subtract is form Colors -> Mix. And yes, I am using an HDR

Comment: no problem. I am sure are other ways to do this in the compositor as well